# Windows Workflow Foundation not compiling 'CSharpValue' expressions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, workflow-foundation-4.5

I have a WWF activity workflow that is defined in a XAML file using the visual editor in VS2015. The workflow compiles to a .NET type which gets instantiated and passed into a WorkflowApplication instance. So in other words, the workflow isn't a dynamic activity, and the XAML isn't loaded at runtime.

The issue I am facing is that expressions aren't being built, which results in `System.NotSupportedException: Expression Activity type 'CSharpValue1' requires compilation in order to run.  Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled`

I have checked, and the workflow's custom tool is set to **MSBuild:Compile** and the build action is set to **XamlAppDef**.

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229129/workflow-foundation-4-5-expression-activity-type-csharpvalue1-requires-compi), but no solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you get to solve it?